# Why do Fresnel-integrals contain $\sqrt{\pi}$?

Tags: integration, transcendental-equations, fresnel-integrals, transcendental-functions

The non-elementary functions

$$ F(x) = \int \sin(x^2)\mathrm dx $$
$$ G(x) = \int \cos(x^2)\mathrm dx $$

will yield

$$ F(x) =\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^k \frac{x^{(4k+3)}}{(2k+1)!(4k+3)}$$
$$ G(x) =\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^k \frac{x^{(4k+1)}}{(2k)!(4k+1)} $$

respectively, If you simply rewrite it to a Taylor series, and then integrate every term

However, some places (for example [integral-calulator.com](https://www.integral-calculator.com/#expr=sin%28x%5E2%29)) claim that the integral is equal to

$$ F(x) =  \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} S\Big(\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} x\Big) + C $$
$$ G(x) =  \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} C\Big(\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} x\Big) + C $$
where
$$S(x)  =\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^k \frac{x^{(4k+3)}}{(2k+1)!(4k+3)} $$
$$C(x)  =\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^k \frac{x^{(4k+1)}}{(2k)!(4k+1)} $$

Where does the $ \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} $ and  $ \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}$ term come from? Why can't one just say that $ F(x) = S(x) + C $ and $ G(x) = C(x) + C $?

Comment: There are two definitions of these integrals  https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FresnelIntegrals.html

Comment: I could be wrong, but much like the highly-related [Error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function), it's defined to have a factor of $\sqrt{\pi}$ due to it's applications often needing to be scaled this way. Perhaps this is a bad analogy, but consider how in physics, converting between angular-frequency and the period of a system uses the equation $T=\frac{2\pi}{\omega}$. The factor of $\pi$ shows up because many of the functions we use with these variables are scaled (either naturally or purposefully) with some factors in mind.